# which protocol for exchanging data between the two iPhone and Server side is better?

Tags: ios, web-services

I am working on an iPhone app that will communicate with back end web server, e.g. pull data and post data, etc.

The project has two part development work: iPhone side and web side. The web developer wants to use SOAP-based that is WCF web service to provide interface for iPhone app, but the iOS developer does not want to, since the WCF is 'big': considering the mobile app performance issue, it seems not suitable for the app.

I want know why you choose to use or not use WCF web service in your iPhone app project. I tend not to use it because it's too much trouble to warp the SOAP request and that seems unnecessary for passing data between ios app and web service. Please share you views on this.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of it depends on your requirements.

ie:

Does the communication need to be transaction safe?
SOAP + WS-AT is useful for transactions.

Does the communication need to be small?
JSON / REST can result in small transmissions, but if you require transactions, your on your own.

A helpful blog that goes on more about this:
http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-soap-when-to-use-each